# If i cancel my AdSense account will it also affect my youtube videos for monetizing

Tags: url, google-adsense

I moved to Netherland from Norway i want to change my bank account and all my adres from Norway to Netherland. So, my question is that if I cancel my AdSense account and  if I make a new account is that ok with my you tube channel with monetizing?

Answer (score 2):

If you are changing your bank account and address, just update the same on Adsense account. You don't need to cancel it as a whole.

Comment: You have the option to change the Adsense account associated with youtube as a whole and that won't affect your monetisation in any way.